# Can not add body with send-MailMessage

Tags: powershell, sendmail

The following code executed successfully without `-Body`

```
PS C:\Users\user001> send-MailMessage -SmtpServer smtp.gmail.com -Cre
dential $mycred -Usessl true -From 'user@test.in' -To 'user2@test.in',
'friend@test.com' -Subject 'Hi Test'
```

This code is not executing, this is with `-Body`

```
PS C:\Users\user001> send-MailMessage -SmtpServer smtp.gmail.com -Cre
dential $mycred -Usessl true -From 'user@test.in' -To 'user2@test.in',
'friend@test.com' -Subject 'Hi Test' -body 'message here'
```

I get below specified error

> Send-MailMessage : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts
>   argument 'true'.

Comment: did you mean `-UseSSL $true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove true after `-UseSsl`. It is a flag, not a named parameter.

Comment: If I remove `-UseSsl`, I get this error `send-MailMessage : The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client
was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS
command first. iu7sm5633807pbc.45 - gsmtp`

Comment: @nien If you pay more attention to the answer you can read that it say: Remove the word `true` after -UseSsl.... ;)

Comment: He said to remove the `true` **after** `-UseSsl`, not to remove the option itself. Alternatively change `-UseSsl true` to `-UseSsl:$true`.